# Implement Google Sign In in an Activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, google-signin

I am implementing Google sign-in in an app and app extends a base Activity (an Activity class) for all other activities. While implementing the Sign in

```
new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this,this).
    addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, signInOptions).build();
```

needs the Fragment activity for the method `enableAutoManage(this,this)`, but I cannot implement `AppCompactActivity` or `FragmentActivity` for my existing class. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your activity implement these:

```
public class GoogleSignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
   ...
}
```

and implement the callback and listener methods. Then you can write your piece of code:

```
new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, signInOptions)
    .build();
```